# Storing Dictionaries with same values

Tags: python

Im trying to keep a separate list of dictionaries from a larger list of dictionaries that have the same dates in format YYYY/MM/DD, for example

```
d = [{"Date": "2020/10/03 3:30", "Name": "John"}, {"Date": "2020/10/03 5:15", "Name": "Harry"}, {"Date": "2020/10/05 6:30", "Name": "Rob"}]
```

The output would be

```
[{"Date": "2020/10/03 3:30", "Name": "John"}, {"Date": "2020/10/03 5:15", "Name": "Harry"}]
```

Currently I have,

```
temp = []
for i in range(len(d)):
   temp = []
    for date in range(len(total)):
        if (total[date]['date'][:10] == total[date+1]['date'][:10]) and date+1 != len(total):
            temp.append(d[i])
```

but this doesn't work for most of the cases and not sure how to implement it, any tips ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension for this. Just split the date string and compare the date part.

```
d = [{"Date": "2020/10/03 3:30", "Name": "John"}, {"Date": "2020/10/03 5:15", "Name": "Harry"}, {"Date": "2020/10/05 6:30", "Name": "Rob"}]

dl = set([x['Date'].split()[0] for x in d])  # unique list of dates

dtall = [[x for x in d if x['Date'].split()[0] == dx] for dx in dl]  # group by date string

print(dtall)
```

Output

```
[[{'Date': '2020/10/05 6:30', 'Name': 'Rob'}], 
 [{'Date': '2020/10/03 3:30', 'Name': 'John'}, {'Date': '2020/10/03 5:15', 'Name': 'Harry'}]]
```

--- Loop version ---

```
d = [{"Date": "2020/10/03 3:30", "Name": "John"}, {"Date": "2020/10/03 5:15", "Name": "Harry"}, {"Date": "2020/10/05 6:30", "Name": "Rob"}]

dl = set()  # a set removes duplicates
for dct in d: # each dictionary
   dt = dct['Date'].split()[0]  # split date\time, keep date
   dl.add(dt)  # add date to set (duplicates are ignored)

dtall = []  # final list
for dt in dl:  # each unique date
   dtdate = []  # list for this date
   for dct in d:  # each dictionary
      if dct['Date'].split()[0] == dt:  # if date matches
          dtdate.append(dct) # add to this date list
   dtall.append(dtdate)  # add date list to main list

print(dtall)
```

Output

```
[[{'Date': '2020/10/05 6:30', 'Name': 'Rob'}], 
 [{'Date': '2020/10/03 3:30', 'Name': 'John'}, {'Date': '2020/10/03 5:15', 'Name': 'Harry'}]]
```

Comment: I like this solution, is it possible to show the loops line by line instead of the one line so I can understand it better ?

Answer (score 0):

```
d = [{"Date": "2020/10/03 3:30", "Name": "John"}, {"Date": "2020/10/03 5:15", "Name": "Harry"}, {"Date": "2020/10/05 6:30", "Name": "Rob"}]

tmp = [d[0]]
    for i in d[1:]:
        flag = False
        for j in tmp:
             if j['Date'].split(' ')[0] == i['Date'].split(' ')[0]:
             flag = True
             break
    if flag:
        tmp.append(i)
```

maybe this can help you

Answer (score 0):

you can use `collections.defaultdict`. Using a dict the added value you can access sublists by key (i.e. the date). You can always work with just `dict.values()` if you prefer.

```
spam = [{"Date": "2020/10/03 3:30", "Name": "John"}, 
        {"Date": "2020/10/03 5:15", "Name": "Harry"}, 
        {"Date": "2020/10/05 6:30", "Name": "Rob"}]

from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import date
from pprint import pprint

eggs = defaultdict(list)
for item in spam:
   d, t = item['Date'].split(' ')
   eggs[d].append(item)

pprint(eggs)
pprint(eggs.values())
```

output

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {'2020/10/03': [{'Date': '2020/10/03 3:30', 'Name': 'John'},
                            {'Date': '2020/10/03 5:15', 'Name': 'Harry'}],
             '2020/10/05': [{'Date': '2020/10/05 6:30', 'Name': 'Rob'}]})
dict_values([[{'Date': '2020/10/03 3:30', 'Name': 'John'}, 
              {'Date': '2020/10/03 5:15', 'Name': 'Harry'}], 
             [{'Date': '2020/10/05 6:30', 'Name': 'Rob'}]])
```